# Check if data frame begins from 1st day of year and add missing dates

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Date_from <- c("2013-01-05","2013-05-10","2013-08-13","2013-11-19")
Date_to <- c("2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-25")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

I am checking if the data frame ends at the last day of the year with the following code:

```
y<-rbind(y, c(as.character(max(as.Date(y$Date_to))+1), paste0(substr(max(as.Date(y$Date_to)), 1, 4),"-12-31")  , NA))
```

How can I do the check at the beginning of the data frame: Check if the data frame begins on the first day of the year and if not add this range to the data frame. The result should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration
2013-01-01 2013-01-04          <NA>
2013-01-05 2013-05-07           1.5
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5    
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5
2013-11-19 2013-12-25           3.5
2013-12-26 2013-12-31          <NA>
```

Comment: do you have multiple years in your data? if you do, do you want each year to be independent of the other or can the date range be from 2013-12-26 to 2014-01-05 ?

Comment: if you are already comfortable with your approach for adding the last date range you can use `y<-rbind(c(paste0(substr(min(as.Date(y$Date_from)), 1, 4),"-01-01")  ,as.character(min(as.Date(y$Date_from))-1),  NA),y)`

Comment: @SatZ I would have each year independent from each other.

Comment: can the to and from date be the same in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added another year to the data you had provided

```
Date_from <- c("2013-01-05","2013-05-10","2013-08-13","2013-11-19","2014-01-05","2014-05-10","2014-08-13","2014-11-19")
Date_to <- c("2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-12-25","2014-05-07","2014-08-12","2014-11-18","2014-12-25")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","2.5","1.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

Add the below snippet to your code and you'll have your result

```
setDT(y)
y1<-y[,.(Date_from=as.Date(as.character(max(as.Date(Date_to))+1)), Date_to=as.Date(paste0(substr(max(as.Date(Date_to)), 1, 4),"-12-31"))  , concentration=NA),by=.(Year=substr(as.Date(Date_to), 1, 4))]
y2<-y[,.(Date_from=as.Date(paste0(substr(min(as.Date(Date_from)), 1, 4),"-01-01")), Date_to=as.Date(as.character(min(as.Date(Date_from))-1))  , concentration=NA),by=.(Year=substr(as.Date(Date_from), 1, 4))]

y<-rbind(y,y1[,.(Date_to,Date_from,concentration)],y2[,.(Date_to,Date_from,concentration)])[order(Date_from,Date_to),][!(Date_to==Date_from & is.na(concentration))]
```

There are neater ways to do this.